# Eclipse RCP maximized editor not showing when migrating to Eclipse photon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a RCP application I have migrated from eclipse indigo to eclipse photon. When I open the editor as before no editor shows up.

However, the editor is indeed correctly loaded as I'm able to access it when minimized ([see image](https://image.prntscr.com/image/-EPfVyvzTJeYZ_y1JSkCZA.png)), but if I try to maximize it, it disappears just showing an empty area ([see image](https://image.prntscr.com/image/x-e8cJMFTqaY9MZ85Q-FVQ.png)) where the editor was shown in eclipse indigo .

Editor is defined in an extension point

```
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        class="arbolDefinicion.editors.ADLEditor"
        contributorClass="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicTextEditorActionContributor"
        extensions="adl"
        icon="icons/c_complex_object.ico"
        id="arbolDefinicion.editors.ADLEditor"
        name="Editor ADL"/>
  </extension>
```

I'm opening/showing the editor part with the lines

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().setEditorAreaVisible(true);
```

then getting the contents of the document with

```
((AbstractDecoratedTextEditor) window.getActivePage().getActiveEditor()).getDocumentProvider().getDocument(((AbstractDecoratedTextEditor) window.getActivePage().getActiveEditor()).getEditorInput());
```

and then setting the contents, which seems to work fine.

The editor is loaded with the following lines:

```
                IEditorInput input=new FileEditorInput(fstorage);

                String editorId= getEditorId(file);

                IWorkbenchPage page= fWindow.getActivePage();

                try {

                    if(page!=null)
                    {
                        IEditorPart part = page.openEditor(input, editorId );
                        page.activate(part);
                    }


                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    log(e);
                }
```

As stated above, there is no errors opening the editor, as it can be accessed if not maximized.

Are there any extra steps in Eclipse photon that are needed to show a maximized editor?

Comment: Does your perspective have an editor area?  The code in `WorkbenchPage#setEditorAreaVisible()` won't create an editor area when `true`.

Comment: The perspective has a `page.setEditorAreaVisible(false);` as the editor part starts hidden, but nothing else dealing with the editor in the perspective, is something else needed in newer versions? (this worked in the past)

Comment: What are you doing to maximize the editor?

Comment: nothing by code, just pressing the maximize button or double clicking the editor title bar, same results with both